# In-app triplestore like SQLite

Tags: open-source, database, c++, cross-platform, rdf

Is there any open-source and cross-platform triplestore that could be integrated into a C++ application?

I’m not looking for servers (i.e. 4store or Soprano). The good example for relational databases is SQLite.

Comment: In [Wikipedia’s Triplestore article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplestore#List_of_implementations), there are listed a few written in C++. Do you have any further requirements?

Comment: @unor I've been looking for an open-source cross-platform one. 4store is not cross-platform. Neither 4store, nor Soprano is in-app, they're servers.

Comment: I see, thanks. I edited your question (feel free to correct it if something is missing/wrong).

Comment: `VistaDB` is the best and the most full-featured, but is commercial

Comment: This should totally be a thing, right?! Embedded, transactional triple store and query engine. BOOM! … ideally syncable / mergeable too. Like SQLite but, … triply. Great analogy, and should be a thing.

Comment: I would just like to note that a little over 6 years after this question was posted, I'm still not aware of a sqlite-ish Triplestore... I ended up using SQLite to emulate one :/

Comment: @Benjohn @TomášM. Good news! We have `cozo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [cozodb](https://github.com/cozodb/cozo) but querying is done in datalog instead of SPARQL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I came back to my question to add exactly this answer. I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

[Oxigraph](https://github.com/oxigraph/oxigraph) is in Rust rather than C++, but you might be able to find a way to call it from C++, or just spawn a subprocess and call the Command-Line Interfaces (CLI).

DeciSym has a [fork](https://github.com/DeciSym/oxigraph) that extends Oxigraph to query HDT files. This is intended to combine the data and SPARQL engine in a transportable way that does not require a server process in the style of SQLite. See https://www.datanami.com/2023/03/02/cyberspooks-need-big-data-portability-too/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

The most actively maintained C++ interfaced non-networked RDF library is [SEMPR](https://github.com/sempr-tk/sempr).

Less active (but project is *not* dead) is the [Redland](https://librdf.org/) set of libraries.

Another less accessible option is [owlcpp](https://github.com/ethz-asl/libowlcpp). Seemingly dead by now, but might be possible to revive - at least the Fact++ dependency still works with up-to-date Debian (I maintain that Debian package).